# PHP: Is it possible to get non blocking output buffer?

Tags: php, console-application

I'm building a console application and would like to use already written code without modifying it. But, I need the output of a command. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
function func() {
    /* Let's say this function contains already written
        code and it would be easier to rewrite it than modify */
    echo 'Confirm action';
    $input = fgets(fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));
    if ($input == 'y') echo 'okay';
    else echo 'no';
    return 0;
}

$code = func();
// func() returns non zero only on error and confirming/declining an action returns 0.
// I want to know if the action was confirmed.
// Using ob_start() prevents echo from working in the function,
// i.e. the user sees a blank screen waiting for input.
```

Is this even possible?

I'm writing this with Yii framework. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with popen, e.g.:

```
    $handle = popen('php yiic migrate create '.$name, 'r');
    $output = '';
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $read = fread($handle, 2096);
        $output .= $read;
        echo $read;
    }
    $exitCode = pclose($handle);
```